# How to display file from the server in a new tab without using blob and data scheme url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, iframe, filereader

**The browser is strict about the URL scheme to use that it only supports `file`, `http`, and `https`**

The front end is using React.js and will receive file data - input stream https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html.

I really hope blob scheme and data scheme are not blocked since I can find a lot of examples

I tried using blob url:

```
window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([buffer], { type: type }));
window.open(url, "_blank");
```

I also tried using FileReader:

```
let reader = new FileReader();
let out = new Blob([buffer], { type: type });
reader.onload = function() {
    window.location.href = reader.result;
};
reader.readAsDataURL(out);
```

Is there anyways I can still display the files without using blob and data scheme? (*I would love to support as many file types as possible - at least "pdf", "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif"*)

Currently, I am considering FileReader and iframe.

Please do not suggest any solutions that involves blob and data scheme. Very appreciated.